# C++: Can you return values of 0 or 1 as false and true in boolean functions?

Tags: c++

can C++ `bool` functions return `0` for `false` and `1` for `true` like so:

```
bool foo() {
    return 1;
}

bool foobar = foo();
```

?

Comment: Can't you just `return (condition);`

Comment: @drescherjm: Probably because the desired semantics are `return !(condition);`  (or were, before the code in the question got changed)

Comment: just asking on principle, guess people really hate this question or something

Comment: Hmm..why is this question so badly received. Everyone was once a beginner and this is a valid question.

Comment: @juanchopanza have you ever looked at the top questions on SO? Most of them are pretty simple to look up on Google too. If you think it's a poor question simply don't look at it.

Comment: @rigdonmr You're right, lately most questions on SO are pretty poor. One of the tools for dealing with that is down-voting. Which is what I did. If more people did that, there wouldn't be so many poor questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because `0` will be implicitly converted to `false` and `1` (or any other nonzero value) will be implicitly converted to `true`.

Not everything legal is a good idea, however.